# pymongo returning different data than MongoDB Shell

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I am playing around with monogdb for an assignment, and I have ran into the following issue: the document returned by `pymongo` doesn't match what is returned by `mongoc`. A simple `test.py`:

```
from pymongo import MongoClient
from bson.objectid import ObjectId

client = MongoClient()
db = client['dev_database']
print db.trials.find_one(ObjectId('522f975dc91e273451569942'))
print list(db.trials.find({'_id':ObjectId('522f975dc91e273451569942')}))
```

Doing it both ways just in case. This returns:

```
{u'nurse_id': u'522f975dc91e273451569941', u'question_ids': [], u'name': u'Test Trial', u'clinician_id': u'522f975dc91e273451569940', u'arms': {u'Med1': u'', u'Placebo': u''}, u'participant_ids': [], u'keywords': [u'abc', u'123'], u'_id': ObjectId('522f975dc91e273451569942')}
[{u'nurse_id': u'522f975dc91e273451569941', u'question_ids': [], u'name': u'Test Trial', u'clinician_id': u'522f975dc91e273451569940', u'arms': {u'Med1': u'', u'Placebo': u''}, u'participant_ids': [], u'keywords': [u'abc', u'123'], u'_id': ObjectId('522f975dc91e273451569942')}]
```

And if I do the same thing inside MongoDB Shell:

```
> use dev_database
switched to db dev_database
> db.trials.find('522f975dc91e273451569942')
{ "_id" : "522f975dc91e273451569942", "nurse_id" : "522f975dc91e273451569941", "question_ids" : [ ], "name" : "Test Trial", "clinician_id" : "522f975dc91e273451569940", "arms" : { "Med1" : "", "Placebo" : "" }, "participant_ids" : [
        "52325b93c91e274e81f4bdda",
        "52325b93c91e274e81f4bddb",
        "52325b93c91e274e81f4bddc",
        "52325b93c91e274e81f4bddd",
        "52325b93c91e274e81f4bdde"
], "keywords" : [ "abc", "123" ] }
>
```

As you can see, `test.py` returns a document where `participant_ids` is an empty list, but MongoDB Shell says otherwise.

I have no idea why this is, and it seems like I must be make a simple, but fundamental mistake somewhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem turned out to be that my code saved a duplicate of this document where `_id` was of type `str`. e.g.

```
> db.trials.find()
{ "_id" : ObjectId("522f975dc91e273451569942"), "nurse_id" : "522f975dc91e273451569941", "question_ids" : [ ], "name" : "Test Trial", "clinician_id" : "522f975dc91e273451569940", "arms" : { "Med1" : "", "Placebo" : "" }, "participant_ids" : [ ], "keywords" : [ "abc", "123" ] }
{ "_id" : "522f975dc91e273451569942", "nurse_id" : "522f975dc91e273451569941", "question_ids" : [ ], "name" : "Test Trial", "clinician_id" : "522f975dc91e273451569940", "arms" : { "Med1" : "", "Placebo" : "" }, "participant_ids" : [
        "52325b93c91e274e81f4bdda",
        "52325b93c91e274e81f4bddb",
        "52325b93c91e274e81f4bddc",
        "52325b93c91e274e81f4bddd",
        "52325b93c91e274e81f4bdde"
], "keywords" : [ "abc", "123" ] }
```

MongoDB Shell always returns the second result, while the test code returns the first. The difference being that my code explicitly casts to `ObjectId`, while MongoDB Shell seems happy to try and find a match using `str` first.

The fact that MongoDB Shell's result lacked the `ObjectId(...)` in the `_id` field should have warned me something was amiss.

Answer (score 0):

What would be the output of the next code?

```
from pymongo import MongoClient
from bson.objectid import ObjectId

client = MongoClient()
db = client['dev_database']
print json.dumps(db.trials.find_one(ObjectId('522f975dc91e273451569942')))
```

Comment: Not surprisingly: `TypeError: ObjectId('522f975dc91e273451569942') is not JSON serializable`

Comment: Sorry, it was my mistake. Seems like .find() returns correct data, but "print list()" doesn't print arrays recursively. Try to read count of objects in participant_ids array. Miracles do not happen.

Comment: Just read one object from mongodb and make sure that his "participant_ids" field is empty. I believe it is not.

Comment: Miracles do not happen, but lists do print recursively. In any case, `len(doc['participant_ids'])` returns 0. Empty list is empty.